# How to loop through list of objects in Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform

I am trying to dynamically fetch list of VMs from azure using external data source and display VM individually.

Below is Powershell script:

```
$rgroup = [Console]::In.ReadLine()
$json = ConvertFrom-Json $rgroup
$name = $json.rg
$vms=(Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $name ).name
foreach ($vm in $vms){
$vmname= $vm |convertTo-json
Write-Output  "{""Name"" : $vmname}"}

Main.tf

variable "resourcegroup" {}
data "external" "test" {
program = ["Powershell.exe", "./vm.ps1"]
query = {
rg = "${var.resourcegroup}"
}}
output "value" {
value = "${data.external.test.result.name}}
```

However, I am getting an error:

> " command "Powershell.exe"   produced invalid JSON: invalid character
>   '{' after top-level value"

Can someone tel me how to loop through list of VMs and display it individually ?

Answer (score 0):

I have written a terraform module to help with adding ssh keys to gcp metadata. it is not a direct answer to your question but it should help you.

```
variable "ssh_keys" {
  type = list(object({
    user = string
    key = string
  }))
  default = [
    {
      user = "terraform"
      key = "~/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub"
    },
    {
      user = "user"
      key = "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
    }
  ]
}
resource "google_compute_project_metadata" "default" {
  metadata = merge(
    {
      ssh-keys = join("\n", [for k,v in var.ssh_keys : "${var.ssh_keys[k].user}:${file("${var.ssh_keys[k].key}")}"])
    }
  )
}
```